# Failure to open write channel after upgrading App Engine Java SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework, google-cloud-datastore, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to upgrade the version of the App Engine SDK we are using for our Play! web application from 1.6.0 to 1.7.6.

After the upgrade we're no longer able to write files to the blobstore of the local development server. We use the following code to write a file:

```
Image img = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(uploadedData);

FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("image/png", "__initial_data/" + vf.getName());

FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);
```

The call to `fileService.openWriteChannel` fails with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestEndListenerHelper.register(RequestEndListenerHelper.java:39)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.open(LocalFileService.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:527)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:481)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:461)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Although the SDK of App Engine is open source, I cannot find the source files for these development-specific classes to find out what is going on internally.

Does anyone know if the implementation details for writing objects to the blobstore has changed since version 1.6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a Play! specific issue. The play-gae module implements it's own LocalServerEnvironment for App Engine, called `PlayDevEnvironment`. This contains a method to get a list of attributes. Between version 1.6.0 and 1.7.7 of App Engine a change was made which needed additional attributes to be returned. We solved it by changing that class as follows:

```
public class PlayDevEnvironment implements Environment, LocalServerEnvironment {

    ...

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put(LocalEnvironment.REQUEST_END_LISTENERS, new ArrayList<RequestEndListener>());
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```